# Does wall of force version forcecage allow air to go through?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

> *Windowless Cell:* This version of the spell produces a 10-foot cube with no way in and no way out. Solid
> walls of force form its six sides.

If it doesn't, would the trapped creature (with the type which needs breath) eventually die due to running out of oxygen?

If it does, can that creature use things like *gust of wind* to blow away the cloud effects (e.g. *Cloudkill*) from that *forcecage* to stop taking damage and other negative effects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since *forcecage* specifies that it has “no way in or out” and that it is (in this mode) comprised of “Solid walls of force,” and *wall of force* specifies that solid walls of force block “breath weapons” among other things, it’s clear that the solid version of *forcecage* produces a sealed chamber.

The game has rules for that:

> A Medium character can breathe easily for 6 hours in a sealed chamber measuring 10 feet on a side. After that time, the character takes 1d6 points of nonlethal damage every 15 minutes. Each additional Medium character or significant fire source (a torch, for example) proportionally reduces the time the air will last. When a character falls unconscious from this nonlethal damage, she drops to -1 hit points and is dying. In the next round, she suffocates.
>
> Small characters consume half as much air as Medium characters. A larger volume of air, of course, lasts for a longer time.

<sup>([Environment → Suffocation](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm#suffocation))</sup>

The rules here consider a 10-foot cubed volume for this: that’s precisely the volume of *forcecage*, and I don’t think that’s a coincidence. This establishes clearly how *forcecage* can affect creatures’ ability to breathe. With a 2 hour/level duration, it’s fairly easy to trap a creature for more than the 6 hours it takes to run out of air.

It doesn’t matter that *forcecage* itself doesn’t consider this possibility: since the default rules include information on what happens if you’re in a sealed chamber and might suffocate, it isn’t necessary for *forcecage* to repeat them. However, it is worth wondering if the authors thought this through: while not strictly **necessary** to note this danger from the spell, they usually would just to remind players of it. The fact that they didn’t may mean they didn’t consider it, and this wasn’t an intended part of the spell. Even if they didn’t intend suffocation as a risk, though, I don’t see any alternative without significantly changing the spell, either to have it produce fresh air, or to be vulnerable to escape via things like *gaseous form*.

*Forcecage* is a 7th-level spell, though—there is an argument to be made that a nominally 13th-level-equivalent entity doesn’t deserve the title if they can’t teleport. It’s possible to simply assume anyone within a *forcecage* can leave whenever they wish to. It’s unlikely that the designers assumed this, though—they assigned CR 13 and higher to many creatures who cannot escape *forcecage* under their own power.

Comment: I thought the duration of *Forcecage* is 2 hours/level (D). Is it actually 1 round/level?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker Whoops, was looking at my *wall of force* tab instead of my *forcecage* tab; you’re correct. Will correct.

Answer (score 2):

### Where do you get the idea air doesn’t pass through a [Wall of Force](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wallOfForce.htm)?

The description doesn’t mention air at all.

- it is immune to damage of all kinds
- it is unaffected by most spells
- breath weapons and spells cannot pass through the wall in either direction
- it blocks ethereal creatures as well as material ones

So, as written oxygen can come in and carbon dioxide can come out. If there’s a strong wind outside, there’s a strong wind inside. If it’s raining outside, it’s raining inside.

> can that creature use things like *gust of wind* to blow away the cloud effects (e.g. *Cloudkill*) from that *forcecage* to stop taking damage and other negative effects?

No, because *gust of wind* is a spell and that’s on the list of things that can’t pass through.